# Does the closure of component set restricted to subspace equals to the closure of component set in the subspace?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ is a topological space, $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, $A \subseteq Y$.
Then I know $$Y\cap Cl_X(A)=Cl_Y(A)$$ holds.

But does 
$$Y\cap Cl_X(X-A)=Cl_Y(Y-A)$$ also holds?

Comment: So your question is $Cl_Y(Y-A)=Cl_Y(X-A)$?

Comment: @Siminore I think not, because $X-A$ may not included in $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is false.

Take for example $X = \mathbb R, Y = [0, 2]$ and $A = [0, 1]$. Then $0 \in Y \cap Cl_X(X - A)$ but $0 \not \in Cl_Y(Y - A)$.

Comment: So that means $Int_Y(A)=Y \cap Int_X(A)$ is also not true in general.

Comment: Yes, the same example applies to it.